# Sinon spy not being called inside an express middleware

Tags: node.js, express, sinon

I'm currently learning to test a jwt authentication express middleware. My next callback is being called because i put a `console.log` there but my sinon spy assertion is failing.

Can someone take a look at this case?

This is my test case

```
  it("should call next when the token provided is valid", () => {
    let token = jwt.sign({}, process.env.JWT);
    let request = httpMocks.createRequest({
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    });
    const next = sinon.spy();
    authenticateJwt(request, response, next);
    expect(next.calledOnce).to.be.true;
  });
```

And here is my middleware

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

export default function(req, res, next){
  const authorizationHeaders = req.headers["authorization"];
  let token;

  if(authorizationHeaders){
    token = authorizationHeaders.split(" ")[1];
  }

  if(token){
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT, (err, decodedToken) => {
      if(err){
        res.status(401).json({
          message: "invalid token provided"
        });
      } else {
        res.user = decodedToken;
        console.log("called");
        next();
      }
    });
  } else {
    res.status(401).json({
      success: false,
      message: "no token provided"
    });
  }
}
```

My `console.log` is logging correctly but the sinon assertion is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Your `expect` is probably happening too early. You are not waiting for the callback to happen before asserting that it has happened.

You probably don't need sinon at all in this example, this should work for you:

```
it("should call next when the token provided is valid", () => {
    let token = jwt.sign({}, process.env.JWT);
    let request = httpMocks.createRequest({
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
    });
    return authenticateJwt(request, response, () => {
        // Do assertions in here
    });
});
```

Perhaps a better way to format it would be:

```
describe('authenticateJwt middleware', () => {
    let nextCalled = false;

    before(() => {
        let token = jwt.sign({}, process.env.JWT);
        let request = httpMocks.createRequest({
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
            }
        });
        return authenticateJwt(request, response, () => {
            nextCalled = true;
        });
    })

    it("should call next when the token provided is valid", () => expect(nextCalled).to.be.true);
});
```

This allows you more flexibility with your assertions. It also ensures it fails if it isn't called for some reason.

Comment: What type of assertions can i do here? I'm still new to testing in general. All I want to test for is that the callback function is called.

Comment: I have editing the answer to provide an alternative with an example assertion

Comment: Hang on, I have one more question. How do i pass the token to each test. I understand that you are using a before hook. But it seems that this only handles cases where tokens are provided. How can I modify this so that it can also handle cases where no tokens are provided?